# Codeigniter - How to get and change uri segement then redirect?

Tags: class, codeigniter, uri

In my web application I have a url that looks like the following:

```
http://mydomain.com/search/index/list/for-sale/london/0/0/0/0
```

I would like to use the uri class and redirect to change `$this->uri->segment(3);` to `map` and then redirect.

So that once redirected and the segment has been changed the url would look like:

/search/index/map/for-sale/london/0/0/0/0

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may need some extra checks, but this would be a simple approach:

```
$segment_to_replace = "/".$this->uri->segment(3)."/";
$new_url = str_replace ($segment_to_replace, "/map/", current_url());

redirect ($new_url);
```

Comment: Very nice approach. Simple and effective. Glad you understood my question. Thanks.